# Liquibase - Contexts by data centers

Tags: sql, liquibase, changelog

I am starting to use the `Liquibase` SQL migration tool. I read the documentation but I'm not sure how the context could apply in my current situation.

I have **4 data centers with 2 environments** each, one of production and another of tests.

Liquibase creates two tables with the log of the applied changes, `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` and all the scripts are applied in the same table, differentiating them from the context.

Is it possible to separate the list of production changes from the test or is it recommended to differentiate it with the context field?

For example:

> Contexts: DC1_PROD, DC1_TEST, DC2_PROD, DC2_TEST, DC3_PROD,
>   DC3_TEST, DC4_PROD, DC4_TEST

Currently our functionality uses SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to replicate the tables with the changes therefore we do not use a centralized system.

Is Liquibase centralized and is it only necessary to have it in a single database?

Comment: Is there all databases have exacltly the same schema?

Comment: @Albert Yes, all databases from each CPD hace the same schema

Comment: So you can run same changes on each instance. I don't see a reason why to use context in this case?

If each DB instance has it's own `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` you can simply run the same changes on each one.